# how to use an image for my custom .desktop file for unity previews

Tags: .desktop, unity-previews

When one left clicks an application, it also displays the screenshot of the desired application.

screenshot of the desired effect:

[image: unity-previews-vlc]

I can't find the `screenshotlink=`? command in the `vlc.desktop` file (and or other `.desktop` files)

This is what I have now:[image: unity-previews-eurobytes]

**Question**: *How to get an image for my custom made `.desktop` file.*

**Note**: *If needed, I can post the code used for my custom  `.desktop` file*

Comment: I'm not in Unity right now, but can you please compare this screenshot I see for Vlc with the screenshot of it that it is available on the Software Center?

Comment: @hakermania I don't know how to get the `vlc.desktop` that is available via software center, but I checked some other default apps; thunderbird, totem, and I couldn't find a the `screenshotlink=` on either of them?

Comment: I don't think that there's a .desktop file associated with every application in Software Center (I highly doubt it), but I just want to know whether USF and Unity Previews use the same mechanism for getting a screenshot of the application (which sounds pretty logical to me). If this is the case, then you will not be able to have a screenshot for a custom application so easily...

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the name of the .desktop files itself relate to applications in software center.

If you copy the `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` to your `~/.local/share/applications` and then rename `firefox.desktop` to (for example) `libreoffice-calc.desktop` (content of the file untouched). Then type in firefox and you'll see in one of the items the preview and comments from libre instead of firefox.

Therefore i think that it is not possible to have own preview images / thumbnails unless your application is in the ubuntu repos.